# Mongoose: Find all Models using array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this Model:

```
const cart = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    products: [{
        productId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Product",
        },
        quantity: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            default: 1
        },
        title: String,
        price: Number
    }],
  },
  { timestamps: true });
```

How I find all my products (from Model Product) using it.

```
cart = Cart.find(id);

// inside cart.products
[{productId: 'asvhbajAS13', quantity: 8 },{productId: 'asvhbajAS13', quantity: 2 }]
```

I want to modify all products after that, is this approach right?

What I've tried:

```
Product.find({
                '_id': { $in: { cart.products } }
             }, function(err, product) {
              
                })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but if you use findOne() .or you can use populate instead of query once more :

```
cart = Cart.find(id).populate("products")
```